# Page becomes unresponsive after closing a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, modal-dialog

I am creating a system for hotel management that manages guests and checkins.

I am having trouble with the response time of my modals.

I have a cancel button inside the modal which closes the modal BUT DOESN'T reload the page. Here's what I got in the cancel button:

```
 $("#cancel").click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     jQuery(".ui-dialog").dialog().dialog('close');
     jQuery(".ui-widget-overlay").dialog().dialog('close');
 });
```

Here's the problem:
When the modal appears (by clicking another button), I click cancel and the code above is to be executed. I did this numerous times (Open modal and cancel) and the page became unresponsive. You have to wait minutes before it closes the modal after doing it for over 5 times. You can't even close the tab of the browser.

Any ideas would be very much welcome. Thank you.

PS.
I uploaded the system to the web for you to see.
http://greenenergiesllc.com/temp

```
Login: joel

Password: 1234
```

PHP file that creates some of my modals: https://www.dropbox.com/s/azi51w0pzp69kgh/checkin.php

Code snippet on how I create a modal:

```
jQuery( "#ex4").dialog({
    height: 'auto',
    width: 450,
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        jQuery(this).parent().children().children('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();
    }, position: ["center", 100],
    resizable: false
});
```

EDIT:

This is what I've done so far. I solved the DOM problem of creating too many objects by adding .remove after the close call.

```
 $("#cancel").click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     jQuery(".ui-dialog").dialog().dialog('close').remove();
     jQuery(".ui-widget-overlay").dialog().dialog('close').remove;
 });
```

However, after closing the modal for the first time, it won't open for the second time and I got this error.
--> UPDATE: Using remove won't bring the modal back when called. I am completely confused now what to do. I need to remove those DOM elements when called by using .remove() but I need to bring them back when called.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method '_focusTabbable' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont need to use like that way. Try

```
$(".ui-dialog").dialog( "close" );
$("#cancel").click(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 $(".ui-dialog").dialog( "close" );
 $(".ui-widget-overlay").dialog('close');
});
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your time.

I tried your code. However I got an error upon opening the modal:
`Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close' `

I uploaded the system to the web for you to see.
http://greenenergiesllc.com/temp

Login: joel
Password: 1234

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not appear to be a problem with the close function.

When you click on link, the modal appears. In this moment, you create one modal in the DOM. See:

[image: DOM Dialog]

If you click many times, you have created many others modals in the DOM. See:

[image: Many HTML here]

The problem is in your function that trigger this modal. With many HTML in your DOM, more slower the "close" function will be.

Comment: Thank you for that observation. This is the file that creates the modals of checkin and checkout.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/azi51w0pzp69kgh/checkin.php

@Line 100, the checkout modal is created. Question is, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: First step: try change your cancel event to this: `$("#cancel").click(function(){ $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close"); });`.  The way you are trying to close the modal, you are creating empty modals in the DOM.

Comment: Hi. Thanks again for your time. I tried your suggestion, I got an error: `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'`. That's the reason why I am using `.dialog().dialog('close');` because it works :)